# Block the background when I make scroll in a UI text in device mobiles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a map in the background and I can move it with the finger. When I tap in some objects of screen it appears a UI text in scroll with information but when I touch the screen to do scroll in the text, the map placed in the background moves in UI devices. In Unity editor works fine. How can I get the map doesn't move in mobile devices?

This is the code to move the background map:

```
if(dragToPan){
    if(!mapping && ready){

        if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

            if(Input.GetTouch(0).position.y > screenY/12){
                Vector2 touchDeltaPosition  = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

                //Check if any of the tile borders has been reached
                CheckBorders();
                //Translate the camera
                cam.Translate(-touchDeltaPosition.x*dragSpeed*Time.deltaTime, -touchDeltaPosition.y*dragSpeed*Time.deltaTime, 0);

                //Clamp the camera position to avoid displaying any off the map areas
                ClampCam();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

void Update(){  
    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() || EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject != null) {           return;         }

And this is how I enable the scroll text:

```
public class SeleccionarTesoro_LIST : MonoBehaviour {

void Start()
{
GameObject[] hitObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TESOROS");
}

public void SetHitObjectToActive(GameObject hitObject)
{
hitObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive (true);
hitObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(2).gameObject.SetActive (true);
}

void Update() {

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);


        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
            SetHitObjectToActive (hit.collider.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something in the lines of:

1 - Create bool isSeleccionarTesoroScrollUp.

2 - Set it to true whenever the scroll text is up, and to false when it is dismissed.

3 - In the map script, you can change if(dragToPan) to

if(dragToPan && !isSeleccionarTesoroScrollUp), or whatever you find it more convenient.

That way the map won't move when you scroll.

Good luck and keep up the good work :)

Comment: My pleasure :)))